# equivalent of if exists in isqlplus?

Tags: sql

I'm new to sql and trying to find out if there is a way to say something like this in isqlplus? I'm trying to insert a row with values if a certain value exists on another table.

```
   IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM SOMETABLE WHERE ID = 1)
   BEGIN
   INSERT INTO ANOTHERTABLE (NBR, FNAME, LNAME) VALUES ( 2, 'John', 'Smith');
   END
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I've tried the solution from Iswanto San, which worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `WHERE EXISTS` in your query

```
INSERT INTO ANOTHERTABLE (NBR, FNAME, LNAME) 
SELECT  2, 'John', 'Smith'
FROM DUAL
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM SOMETABLE WHERE ID = 1)
```